# How does a browser understand a subnet mask in IPv4?

Tags: ipv4, subnet

I am a newbie in network engineering. Now, I want to know how a browser understands a subnet mask in IPv4. For example, `78.39.197.180` with `255.255.0.0` is a unique address, and `78.39.197.180` with `255.255.255.0` is a unique address, too. So, when i put the address in a browser, how can the browser understand which one of those is my need?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Those two addresses are the same, there's not distinction. Changing the netmask does not make it a different IP address, it just changes which range of addresses is considered to be the local network.

Also, browsers do nothing with netmasks, they only know IP addresses and DNS names. You can't enter a netmask in a browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. now imagine that we have 2 local network that connect with together. we have 2 computers in those networks that using as web server. one of them , has 192.168.1.10 (subnet mask : 255.255.255.0) and another has 192.168.1.10 (subnet mask : 255.255.0.0). when i put this IP address in browser , which one of them will be called ?

Comment: That is a error condition.  You cannot have two hosts with the same IP address.  In that case, traffic will always go to the subnet with the longer mask, in this case, 255.255.255.0

Comment: @watermelon - depends entirely on your router that is connecting those two networks, which is the only item in your setup that's paying attention to what is where.  It will also likely be a very confused and likely unreliable router, as you've told it to route two networks with very similar IPs.  In short, don't do this, take steps (even NAT) to make them different.